# How do I get back into creative mode from being stuck in adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently creating a server for some friends and me to play on, and I needed to change the game mode to adventure within a certain radius. I have an underground room where all of my command blocks are that I'm usually in creative for, but since I put a command block in which sets all players in a 75 block radius into adventure mode, I'm currently stuck in the room because I can't get into creative mode to fly out.

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Do you still have cheats enabled? As in can you run commands? I assume that you can't just disable the command block that is turning you into adventure mode because you have to be in creative mode to do that, but you can use /setblock to turn the command blocks into air blocks, thus disabling the effect. Then you just have to remember to build an exit staircase and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `/setblock ~ ~-0.5 ~ minecraft:air destroy` while standing on the command block in order to remove it and thus stop it from setting you into adventure mode, and then you can use `/gamemode` to put yourself back into creative.